# Why doesn't Federation mandatorily always use "Signal Jammer" against the Borg?

Tags: star-trek

The nastiest thing about the Borg is its Collective Intelligence. Remove it and individual drones won't be able to do anything big.

From the canon, individual Borg drones (disconnected from the collective) don't go crazy and they do work on their own asynchronously. But, without the access to the collective, they can't do strategic moves due to lack of co-ordination with other drones. Even local (disconnected) collective work in co-ordination.

For example, without the access to the/a collective, an individual drone can't adapt to energy weapons or the situation.

Why doesn't the Federation exploit this weakness simply by jamming the signal of the collective?

As I have recalled, Data once exploited the communication network (using infected Picard) to blow out Borg ship. But, this is not what my question seeks.

What are disadvantages of jamming the collective signal as anti-Borg mandate? Why isn't Federation using it?

Comment: I don't think such technology has ever been shown to exist...

Comment: @Izkata No, subspace communication jammers do exist in the canon. They have blocked ship communications.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Do we have evidence the Borg utilize the same technology as other species do for their communications?

Comment: @Valek Yes. That's why Data was able to use it once. Read the question again.

Comment: **Data** Exploits are usually patched once they're observed in the wild. Presumably the Borg had decent IT techs to tackle the problem. Likely it was a simple buffer overflow attack; a bit of sloppy code that snuck in while the collective was tired, but working to meet deadline.

Comment: @Izkata, pretty sure they used some kind of jamming technology to prevent Hugh from contacting the collective.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Borg exists as the ultimate adaptive bio-mechanical beings in main cannon. Jamming their [subspace communications](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Subspace_communication) would mean nothing. They would adapt. Besides they didn't even use subspace they used [transwarp signals](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transwarp). Drones have subspace transmitters but ships use transwarp to communicate. Starfleet never understood how to travel in transwarp or the basis of the physics required to do as you suggest even with the help of [Seven](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Seven_of_Nine) (ex Borg most intelligent human in existence. with knowledge of many people like Data). Even the hyper advanced One (the transporter child of [the Doctor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Mobile_emitter) and Seven) from the [voyager episode drone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drone_%28Star_Trek:_Voyager%29) couldn't keep the Borg ship from constant communication from the collective.

So Borg ships are like hubs and drones are like spokes and transwarp conduits are like axials with the queen being the driver. In the absence of a ship with a working transwarp drive [mini collectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_of_Nine) form between the drones. They carry a mini copy of the collective in their head as well so they would be able to guess at the next action the collective will take when communication is broken like what Seven did during the [species 8472 war](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Borg-Species_8472_War).

*Outside of main cannon* [multiphasic defenses](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Multiphasic_shield) (including personal shields) and [transphasic arsenals](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transphasic_torpedo) were generalized (not just torpedoes but phasers and whole ships went transphasic and kamikazed Borg cubes) in a way to successfully defeat them for 10 minutes in mass but because there are so many Borg it did little good as they adapted. The ultra powerful [Caeliar](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Caeliar_gestalt) were able to transform all the Borg into members of their gestalt using subspace tunnels and programmable matter. At which time they left the galaxy for places and time periods unknown.

Comment: I've downvoted. There's elements of an excellent answer here but you need to reference and not assume that the questioner knows all the intricacies of Star Trek lore. Note also that the Caeliar are not part of the established TV canon.

Comment: @Richard I cite a voyager episode and all the new books blab about transphasic this and multiphasic that so its not really issolatable (and don't even get them started on quantum slipstream lest you fall into a never ending typhoon pack series) but the main war with the borg happens in lost souls and gods of night. I don't really know how to cite the transwarp com and subspace com stuff maybe a good trip to memory alpha (which i guess others dont have memorized for shame lol ;) )?

Comment: Much improved. Upvoted.